# Find the Galois group of the field $\mathbb{k}_{sym}(x_1,\dots,x_n)(D)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Find the Galois group of the field $\mathbb{k}_{sym}(x_1,\dots,x_n)(D)$ over the field $\mathbb{k}_{sym}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, the characteristic of $\mathbb{k}$ is 2 and $$D(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}(x_i - x_j)$$
I seem to know all the definitions, but don't really understand what to begin with.

Comment: I suppose $\mathbb{k}_{sym}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ denotes the symmetric functions in $x_1,\dots,x_n$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\mathrm{sgn}}$
First of all, start with $E = \mathbb{k}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, and with its group of field automorphisms $S_{n}$. The fixed field is $F = \mathbb{k}_{sym}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Galois theory tells you that $E / F$ is Galois, with Galois group $S_{n}$.

Now take $D = D(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Writing permutations on the right, you should know that if $\sigma \in S_{n}$, then
$$
D(x_1 \sigma,\dots,x_n \sigma)
=
\sgn(\sigma) \cdot D(x_1,\dots,x_n).
$$
Therefore *if the characteristic of $\mathbb{k}$ is not $2$*, you obtain that $D \notin F$, but $D^{2} \in F$, and $F(D)$ is invariant under all elements of the Galois group of $E/F$. Thus $F(D)/F$ is Galois, and the Galois group of $F(D)/F$ is cyclic of order $2$.

On the other hand, *if the characteristic of $\mathbb{k}$ is $2$*, as per assumption, $D \in F$, as it is fixed by all the elements of the Galois group of $E/F$, and thus $F(D) = F$, so the Galois group is trivial.